# How can I connect FCM server using any reliable XMPP library in C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, push-notification, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can anybody help me in connecting FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) server using XMPP library using C#?

I want to send Push notification using XMPP.

I am trying to connect it using Sharp.Xmpp as below,

```
public class XmppConnector
    {
        public XmppConnector()
        {
            string hostname = "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
            string username = "exmple@gcm.googleapis.com";
            string password = "example";

            using (XmppClient client = new XmppClient(hostname, username, password))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Setup any event handlers before connecting.
                    client.Message += OnNewMessage;
                    // Connect and authenticate with the server.
                    client.Connect();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked whenever a new chat-message has been received.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnNewMessage(object sender, Sharp.Xmpp.Im.MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message from <" + e.Jid + ">: " + e.Message.Body);

            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

But it does not work, I even tried with another port (5235 and 5236). If you have any examples, do share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/ForNeVeR/Jabber-Net

```
myJabberClient = new JabberClient();
myJabberClient.User = Globales.FIRABASE_MESSAGING_USER + "@gcm.googleapis.com";
myJabberClient.Password = Globales.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_KEY;
myJabberClient.Server = Globales.FIRABASE_GCM_XMPP_SERVER;
myJabberClient.Resource = "MyTestClient";
myJabberClient.Port = 5235;
myJabberClient.AutoReconnect = 1;
myJabberClient.AutoPresence = false;
myJabberClient.AutoRoster = false;
myJabberClient.KeepAlive = 10;
myJabberClient.PlaintextAuth = true;
myJabberClient.AutoLogin = true;
myJabberClient.AutoStartTLS = false;
myJabberClient.SSL = true;

myJabberClient.OnMessage += async (s, msg) => {
   // Do stuff here
}

myJabberClient.Connect();
```

I do push notifications with HTTP API.
I'm only having problem sending ACK message of upstream received messages to CCS Server, because the ":" character in some registrarion ids

Answer (score 0):

I did it using Jabber-net library, which you can download from,
[here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jabber-net/), it includes library and some examples to understand about how to connect to fcm,also it can download through the nuget package manager package name is 
**jabber-net** select the latest version. check [here](https://github.com/hasi006/jabber-net-fcm) for configured sample.